# Oauth authorization server with custom authentication manager in Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have multiple authentication managers in the application. I distinguish them by bean name. Part of my xml configuration related to oauth authorization server looks like and it works fine:

```
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" >
    <oauth:authorization-code disabled="true" />
    <oauth:implicit disabled="false" />
    <oauth:refresh-token disabled="false" />
    <oauth:client-credentials disabled="false" />
    <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="resource-id" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="oauthClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

I'm trying to move it to Java based configuration (in some SecurityConfig class), without lack so far. I've tried something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Resource
    private OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Resource(name = "clientDetails")
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Resource
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Resource
    private TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class OAuth2ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Resource(name = "authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenServices(tokenServices).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

however it still complains about multiple authentication managers, although I explicitly set `endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)`.

With some debugging I can see it tries to configure it within class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and it meets multiple authentication manager within `authenticationManager()`. Am I able to override it or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AuthorizationServer - here there is a way to prevent Spring to fail on
   `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#authenticationManager` by simply overriding method
   `org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` - [explanation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/ec215f79f4f73f8bb5d4b8a3ff9abe15b3335866/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration.java#L63)
2. ResourceServer - unfortunately there is no way for similar handling corresponding problem. Best what you can do is decreasing number of instances of global authentication managers to exactly one.